# IClass does not contain a definition of method_name and no extension method method_name

Tags: c#, interface, solid-principles

I am not sure why im having the following error for this code :

"IClass does not contain a definition of method_name and no extension method "method_name" accepting argument of first type IClass (are you missing ref / assembly)"

```
interface IClass
{
   void Calculate();
}

class A : IClass
{
  public A()
  {
  }

  public void Calculate()
  {
    ...
  }

  public void method_name()
  {
    ... 
  }    
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IClass cal;
        cal = new A();
        A.method_name();
    }
}
```

The error is at A.method_name(); i get error that says "IClass" does not contain a definition of "method_nam" and no extension method "method_name" accepting argument of first type ...

May i know why is it so ? I thought we will be able to ref an object to an interface type provided the object inherit the interface. This is part of SOLID approach isn't it ?

What reference do i need to add in if my Interface is in the same file (file.cs) for example.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `cal.method_name();` ? I would have expected `A.method_name()` to error, but with a different message

Comment: method_name is not static  so you cant use like that

Comment: @MarcGravell I have the method but it's not able to call . Im not sure why. Is it because my interface is in the same file ? Based on some googling, people usually place their interface file in another folder. But i don't think it matters for small program. ( just practicing some programming with interface ) .

Comment: @miechooy ? what should i do to be able to use the method_name ?

What i saw on tutorials most of them declare the methods like that too tho. Unless im missing something there.

Comment: @BC2 I explained all of this several minutes ago in an answer...

Answer (score 3):

`A.method_name()` will fail with CS0120:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'A.method_name()'

This is because `method_name()` is an instance method, so it needs to know what object you intended to invoke the method on. `A.method_name()` is the syntax for invoking a `static` method (where there is no `this`).

---

Assuming (based on the message you report) that you actually meant `cal.method_name()`, the compiler is right: `method_name` is only defined on `A`, but your variable is of type `IClass`, so only members *known to be on `IClass`* are available. The fact that the instance *is* an `A` is irrelevant: you are working to the `IClass` contract; the only method available to you will be `Calculate()`, because `IClass` advertises that. If you want to retain access to all the features of `A`: don't type the local variable as `IClass`:

```
A cal;
cal = new A();
cal.method_name();
```

or

```
var cal = new A();
cal.method_name();
```